# Sax parser getting stuck When parsing Html as string

Tags: java

I am using sax parser to parse XML as string in my application .When my code send HTML body as string then sax parser getting stuck for longer time (more than 5 hour).

Page source url : "http://www.cityam.com/taxonomy/term/1/all/feed" which i want to parse.
This url giving HTML page instead of XML.
How to handle this kind of problem or how to get out from my saxParser with appropriate exception.
My code is here

```
public List<RssEntry> parseDocument(String body) {
    // expected body is xml but getting stuck when get body of html page.
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();   
        parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes("UTF-8")), this);
    }

    some catch block
```

Please help me.Thanks

Comment: There's a good chance that the HTML isn't valid XML. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by stuck?  Are your callbacks in your Handler actually being called?  Are there any exceptions being thrown?

Comment: @ sven - but how to get out from here if html not valid

Comment: @Dave - My Application stop responding.and control not getting out from parser code.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably not the problem. I would have expected you would get an error or exception in that case (though online xml validators claim it has lots of errors (e.g. www.xmlcheck.com)).

Comment: Can you post some more of your code, e.g. some of your callbacks?

Comment: @SvendHansen - I have catch block but control not going out from try block

Comment: @MatthewH - This is my code from where i am calling sax parser 
  Set<Item> extractedItms = new HashSet<Item>();
  try {
   RDFParser rdfParser = new RDFParser();
   List<RssEntry> entries = rdfParser.parseDocument(response); // Parsing RDF type documents
   for (RssEntry entry : entries) {
    Item it = createNewItem(entry);
    if (it != null) {
     extractedItms.add(it);
    }
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   Log.error("Exception:", e);
  }
  return extractedItms;

Comment: Are you actually getting into the parseDocument method?  Are you sure the problem is not with getting the page contents from the URL?

Comment: @DaveJohnston- Ya i check, Even print the body.Body Reaching there correctly but control not going out even with any exception.

Comment: And the code works fine if you pass in a different XML string?

Comment: @DaveJohnston-Yes. only this particular site it getting hang in try block when i pass page source as string.

Comment: I have tried it myself by setting up a connection to that URL and passing the InputStream to the SAXParser in the same manner you have done and it works fine.  I can see no reason for it to block if you are passing a String to the parser as you say.  I can only see a possibility of hanging during the request to the URL to get the contents.

Comment: @DaveJohnston- First I fetching body of page it coming without any problem i print it and then i am passing it to parser as string but i getting hang. i am sending the code as follow : RequestData reData = le.fetchHttp(strurl, false, null,true, null);
   RDFParser rdfParser = new RDFParser();
   System.out.println(reData.getResponseBody());
   List<RssEntry> entries = rdfParser.parseDocument(reData.getResponseBody()); 
   System.out.println(entries.size()); fetchhttp() fetching content from the url i print it and send it to parser but control not coming back to main method.

Comment: Can you try taking out all the code from your handler callbacks and replacing with simple logging messages to check whether any of your callbacks are actually being called.  Start with startDocument just to see if the parser is even starting at all.

Comment: @DaveJohnston- I do what u suggest . When i call parse.parse(/*my page body as string*/,/*my handler*/) control  going in startElement or in endElement But time is too long(its vary from 1 hour to two hour).i think parser stuck in infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

When my code send HTML body as string then sax parser getting stuck for longer time (more than 5 hour).
If i pass body of html page which contains "http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd" in dtd are (start of html page) then sax parser got busy to load external-dtd.

so i put these feature as false then sax parser throw an error if xml is not well defined.

XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd",false);

Thanks everybody to help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
// expected body is xml but getting stuck when get body of html page.
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
if(!body.startsWith("<?xml")){
    throw new NotXmlInputException(message); //your exception
}
```

or create shema file for your xml, and use validation

```
SchemaFactory constraintFactory =
        SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Source constraints = new StreamSource(/* your schema */);
Schema schema = constraintFactory.newSchema(constraints);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

try {
    validator.validate(/* convert your string to sourse*/);
} catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException e) {
    log("Validation error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

or may be helped use

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(true);
```